Tomcat 9 on Ubuntu - where does the initial Xmx come from?
Installed Tomcat 9.0.89 on ubuntu, with openjdk 11.0.22.. without altering anything, starting up Tomcat I see
/usr/lib/jvm/java-... -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server ... 

Where does those -Xms/x come from? I cannot find any thing about that in the *.sh files in Tomcats bin folder. Created an setenv.sh file, thought I could overwrite the default values with
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx2048M"

but that only gives me two -Xmx in the start commando. I'd like to understand where the "initial" comes from..

Not an exact duplicate, but this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8596067/462006 it's default heap size that is set in the JVM and can be set with env variables. Note CATALINA_OPTS is the windows var, for ubuntu use JAVA_OPTS

Tell us what you downloaded and how you installed Tomcat. And how did you start it?

@queeg downloaded from tomcat.apache.org, start it with systemctl start tomcat

@scrappedcola well.. as far as I can read, CATALINA_OPTS is not Windows specific, but more that JAVA_OPTS is for all tomcat instances, and CATALINA_OPTS is for "this" instance my source
Also.. there ARE no mentions in neither of tomcats bin/*.sh files of Xmx, but there still is one in actual command being run.

@spinemelter Please add concise information to your question. You downloaded https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.89/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.89.zip, unpack it and startup via systemctl? It means something else is running - not the Tomcat you installed.

Have a look how Tomcat can get controlled by systemd. That's where you should see that environment variables cat get set independently of the location you were searching so far. https://serverfault.com/questions/1105633/how-to-add-tomcat-to-tomcat-service-for-systemctl-startup

@queeg yes.. thanks! I DID download via apache tomcat, but then I created a System Unit file.. pretty new to Ubuntu, followed a guide. And there it was.

As @queeg mentioned.. I looked in the System Unit file (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service on my system) and there it was. Thanks for pointing at the source of the "problem"!
